# Android layout - equally spaced buttons

Tags: android, xml, button

I have two buttons one to save to sd card and other to share it ( an image )
I need them to be equal , each is to the half of the screen ..

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSD"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Save to SD Card"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight=""/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

atm share is more than save to sd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="Share"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSD"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:text="Save to SD Card"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You don't really need to set .5 as weight. These are just relative values. It is only important that you set the same value for both and as thujeevan pointed correctly, to set the dimesion you want to equalize to 0dp.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight). This will allow you to define the size of your buttons proportionally, making them equal if you want. Remember to set your layout_width or layout_height to 0px, depending on the orientation.

You will also need to change to a LinearLayout to use this.